# SSL configuration for logstashAppender on logback-android

Tags: android, logback

I'm looking for a solution to communicate with logstash using custom certificate.

I tried the suggested configuration for the logstash appender with a custom keystore but it's not working as it. How can I load my keystore for logback-android to use it?

```
    <appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <!-- Change te host! -->
        <destination>host</destination>
        <ssl>
            <keyStore>
                <location>path to trustore</location>
                <password>password</password>
            </keyStore>
        </ssl>
        <!-- encoder is required -->
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>
```